# Android: Stop song before playing a new one.

Tags: android, audio, task, repeat

I try to play a song when I receive an SMS,
when I receive 2 SMS then song play simultaneously.

Thanks for your help

```
           Runnable stopPlayerTask = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mPlayer.stop();
                }
            };

            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
            }else{
                mPlayer.seekTo(startime);
                mPlayer.start();
                mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            }
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(stopPlayerTask, endtime);
```

Comment: First, check if you are having single instances of the player. If you are having multiple instances than need to check using any static variable to take care of running state and stop the one you like to.

Comment: is your mplayer delcraed as static?

Comment: Thanks Khan, if you can put an exemple. Please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intended use of the mediaPlayer correctly, you should be requesting Audio Focus from the Android system. Therefore, you can have the mediaplyer wrapped in a service that implements "AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener". If you implement the callbacks correctly for your application, then the song should never play simultaneously.

*Note that Android requires an API level of at least 8 to use AudioManager*

Here is the reference in the documentation for this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: Ok, are you still experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `mPlayer.reset();` after `mPlayer.stop();`
This will reset all initialization ex: track URI etc so will have to set again track URI before `mPlayer.start();`

This will let only new and one track play at a time and will stop & reset previous track completely.